# How to convert List<Object> into List<T>?

Tags: java, android, list, object, generics

This is the code for getting retrofit response as an object. The below method is working fine but I need an one common function for performing the above functionality, i.e the class name may vary. (e.g) ticket, price, token, appointment like this:

```
processGETRequest(AppController.getApiHelper().searchTickets(from, to), new RetrofitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Object object) { }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Object> object) {

        // Here I'm getting retrofit response as a object //

        if (object != null) {

            // Below method is working fine //

            List<Ticket> ticketList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Object result : object) {
                String json = new Gson().toJson(result);
                Ticket model = new Gson().fromJson(json, Ticket.class);
                ticketList.add(model);
            }

            // I need an one common function for performing above functionality
            // i.e the Class name may vary.. (e.g) Ticket, Price, Token, Appointment like this.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String error) {
        Log.d("error: ", " " + error);
    }
}, false);
```

The `RetrofitListener` interface is simply:

```
public interface RetrofitListener {
    void onSuccess(Object object);
    void onSuccess(List<Object> object);
    void onError(String error);
}
```

Comment: Also, why the JSON parsing? You can just cast the result to a Ticket. `ticketList.add((Ticket) result);`

Comment: i write a one common method to fetch all of the api, so im collecting all the response from retrofit as a object/ list of objects. then i parsing the result  to required class as above written

Comment: Are you using retrofit 2 for this, can you post the service class and RetrofitListener class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a static function similar to:

```
static <T> List<T> toList(List<Object> object, Class<T> desiredClass) {
    List<T> transformedList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (object != null) {
      for (Object result : object) {
          String json = new Gson().toJson(result);
          T model = new Gson().fromJson(json, desiredClass);
          transformedList.add(model);
      }
    }
    return transformedList;
}
```

Basically you just need to ensure that you deliver the desired type (e.g. `desiredClass`) and use it in `fromJson`.

Sample usage:

```
List<Ticket> ticketList = toList(object, Ticket.class);
List<Price> priceList = toList(object, Price.class);
```

Note that by moving the `object != null` into the `toList`-method you do not need to care about what is passed to that method. You at least get an empty list in return.

Comment: wow... was only 20 mins away and the answer prepared but not send... and already 4 others.. 1 deleted already... I am getting old

Answer (score 0):

```
<T> List<T> getList(Class<T> type, List<Object> object) {
    return object.stream()
            .map(result -> new Gson().toJson(result))
            .map(new Gson().fromJson(json, type))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

List<Ticket> ticketList = getList(Ticket.class, object);
```

This will do what your for-loop did.

Comment: you are right, using stream is not a great idea since it needs API >= 24. However stream API is a great feature. I should consider using LightWeght Stream API https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API

Comment: Also we can use RxJava Sequence instead of Stream.

Comment: All you guys, you are right, it is a java 8 main "stream" solution. In fact a `List<Object>` that are actually T's, would be feasible too, without streams, just the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the snippet

```
if (object != null) { 
                        List<Ticket> ticketList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (Object result : object) {
                            String json = new Gson().toJson(result);
                            Ticket model = new Gson().fromJson(json, Ticket.class);
                            ticketList.add(model);
                        }    
                    }
```

with generics like this

```
<T> void check(Class<T> type, List<Object> object) {
        List<T> ticketList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object result : object) {
            String json = new Gson().toJson(result);
            T model = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
            ticketList.add(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this solution. It will work.
`result.getClass()` will automatically check for the class from the `object`.

If you are still not satisfied you can just pass `Class<T> type` to the method `check(Class<T> type, List<Objects> object)` and change `T model = new Gson().fromJson(json, result.getClass());` to `T model = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);`

Answer (score -1):

As according to your question you want a generic code to get List which can be of Any? type.

```
List<Ticket> ticketList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Object result : object) {
                        String json = new Gson().toJson(result);
                        Ticket model = new Gson().fromJson(json, Ticket.class);
                        ticketList.add(model);
                    }
```

is this what you want?

```
List<Ticket> ticketList // can be List<T>??
```

Then create a generic method to get list and use it any where:

```
public <T> List<T> getObjectToList(Object obj, Class<T[]> ObjectArryaClass) {
    String json = new Gson().toJson(obj);
    return Arrays.asList(new Gson().fromJson(json, ObjectArryaClass));
}
```

call above method as:

```
@Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Object> object) {

        // Here I'm getting retrofit response as a object //

        if (object != null) {

            // Below method is working fine //

            List<Ticket> ticketList = getObjectToList(object,Ticket[].class)

            // I need an one common function for performing above functionality
            // i.e the Class name may vary.. (e.g) Ticket, Price, Token, Appointment like this.
        }
    }
```

Comment: getObjectToList(object,Ticket[].class)
u can use any Class instead of Ticket class.
but always give the T[].ckass